# gRPC C++ server cannot detect caller

Tags: grpc

I have multiple gPRC services in the same server.  Some of the endpoints I want to restrict that they are only connected to from the local host not a remote call.  On the server side is this information available to me?  My server is C++.  I am considering writing a grpc::AuthMetadataProcessor to see if I can identify this using the certificate on a TLS connection.  Is this the way to handle this?  Also for non secure connections is there an option to get the caller address?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you could use [this method](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_context_impl.h#L257-L261) to get the peer address. You should be able to call it on a `ServerContext` object. From the comments of this method, it looks like no authentication is needed so I think `InsecureServerCredentials` would also work in this case.

Hope it helps :-)